# How to extract XML data

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have a XML file that has the following data,

```
<extcode Type="abc" Code="12345" />
```

I want to be able to extract the Code, i.e., 12345, for rows where Type is abc. I tried

```
XPathSelectElements("Type[@name='abc']")
```

but it returned nothing.

Thanks.

Edit I figured out that the problem is with namespace. The XML file is like `aw:extcode` instead of just `extcode` and that caused the query to not work properly. How should I do it in the presence of namespace? When I tried to use

```
XmlNameTable nameTable = doc.NameTable;
```

compiler complains that it can't resolve NameTable.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a list of several alternative ways to evaluate an XPath expression on an XML document with namespaces. I have included a collection of links to the relevant MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd use LINQ to XML, as my preferred way of working with XML data. Something like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

int code = doc.Descendants("extCode")
              .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Type") == "abc")
              .First()
              .Attribute("Code");
```

One reason why your XPath isn't working may be that the attribute is called "Type" rather than "name" though...

Comment: +1 for LINQ to XML as its a good way to write code in a more expressable manner.

Answer (score 3):

Use this XPath: `//extcode[@Type = 'abc']/@Code`

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this ↓

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var x = doc.Root.XPathSelectElement("./extcode[@Type='abc']");
        Console.WriteLine("x:" + x.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/FolderName/FileName.xml"));

var output= from obj in xmlDoc.Element("extcode")
            where obj.Attribute("Type").Value.ToLower() == "abc"
            select obj;

DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();
outputTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("code"));

foreach (var item in output)
{
   DataRow outputRows = outputTable.NewRow();

   if (outputRows != null)
   {
      outputRows["Code"] = item.Element("code").Value;
   }
}
outputTable.Rows.Add(problemsRows);
outputTable.AcceptChanges();
```

now we have output data table you can use the data where ever you need .

Answer (score 0):

> Edit I figured out that the problem is
>   with namespace. The XML file is like
>   aw:extcode instead of just extcode and
>   that caused the query to not work
>   properly. How should I do it in the
>   presence of namespace?

Writing an XPath expression to be applied on an XML document with namespaces is one of the most FAQ about XPath.

**Use the [`XmlNode.SelectNodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx) overload that has an [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) as its second argument**.

The first linked-to page has a complete code example suitable for your case.

Alternative ways are to use **[XPathNavigator.Evaluate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tca6aekc.aspx)** or **[XPathNavigator.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k4x060d.aspx)** overloads that use as their second argument **[IXmlNamespaceResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmlnamespaceresolver.aspx)**.

With LINQ you can use the **[Extensions.XPathEvaluate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353773.aspx)** method.